# setcookie return false in PrestaShop Cart

Tags: php, cookies, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, setcookie

I'm having a problem with PrestaShop 1.6

I'm losing items added to cart by refreshing the page. I am sure it's because id_cart coming from the cookie was reset.

Making a debug I modified Classes / Cookie.php file like follows:

Before:

```
if (PHP_VERSION_ID <= 50200) /* PHP version > 5.2.0 */
    return setcookie($this->_name, $content, $time, $this->_path, $this->_domain, $this->_secure);
else
    return setcookie($this->_name, $content, $time, $this->_path, $this->_domain, $this->_secure, true);
```

After:

```
if (PHP_VERSION_ID <= 50200) /* PHP version > 5.2.0 */
    $respo = setcookie($this->_name, $content, $time, $this->_path, $this->_domain, $this->_secure);
else
    $respo = setcookie($this->_name, $content, $time, $this->_path, $this->_domain, $this->_secure, true);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($respo);
echo "</pre>";
return respo;
```

The result is:

> bool(false)

The result is "TRUE" for the whole site, except of Ajax-cart, which turned out FALSE.

Can you suggest how to fix this or how to make a good debugging?

Comment: Check your log for a warning about "Headers already sent". If you see that, follow the solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Have you checked if there are some overrides? Which theme are you using?

Comment: Default themes and not have override.